# How to add the current git branch to the existing bash prompt

Tags: bash

I'm trying to modify my bash prompt to include the current git branch. This is complicated by the fact that there is already a set of rules that determines what the prompt might be - whether it includes color text, whether the user is on xterm etc. ... so what I really want is to be able to combine the string representing the git branch, colors and all, with the previously set prompt.

But I can't even get the most basic implementation to work. The following includes several of my attempts as I try to simplify the script to eliminate possible problems.

```
# Add current git branch, if any
parse_git_branch() {
 git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}

#PS1="\[\e[34m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[00m\]$PS1 "
#PS1 = "\$(parse_git_branch) $PS1 "
#PS1 = "\$(parse_git_branch) "
#PS1 = "$(parse_git_branch) "
PS1 = $(parse_git_branch)
```

Essentially they all produce the same message:
`PS1: command not found`

I'm sure I am missing something simple. Can anyone tell me what it is?

Comment: Did you try `PS1=$(parse_git_branch)` to not make the shell interpret `PS1` as a command but as an assignment? Your function will however not be executed more than once like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you get is because of the spaces surrounding `=`, as bash attempts evaluates `PS1` as a command, and fails.

You can fix it by just removing the spaces. Here is a sample prompt that prints the current user and directory, along with the prompt:

```sh
export PS1='[\u@\h] \W :: $(parse_git_branch)> '
```

**Note** the single quotes - if you instead use double quotes, the `parse_git_branch` will be evaluated and will not update on every prompt. As an alternative to single quotes, you can escape the `$` if you prefer.

If you want to update your existing prompt to also have the git branch, you can print the current value of the `PS1` environment variable and modify it to suit your needs, finally adding the modified version in say your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: You got my vote but I'd suggest using `git branch --show-current` instead of the extra parsing too. `export PS1='[\u@\h] \W :: $(git branch --show-current 2>/dev/null)> '`

Comment: `PS1` should probably not be exported: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/247585/118235

Answer (score 1):

In case you're willing to use an existing solution, there's a Git prompt function already included in many Linux distros. How to use:

```
PS1=…'$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")'…
```

The mixed quotes are intentional, and the single quotes are necessary to make this run every time the prompt is displayed. Replace the ellipses with the rest of the prompt, such as `'\$ '`. If `__git_ps1` isn't available out of the box see [the full code](https://gitlab.com/victor-engmark/tilde/-/blob/48ccdef08b40afcc2532634007789625cd8af4d9/.bashrc#L124) for a cross-platform solution (works on at least Ubuntu and Arch Linux; should work on recent NixOS).

The `" (%s)"` part is the format string, that is, a space, open parenthesis (because I want to keep this info separate from the rest of the prompt), the prompt string, and close parenthesis. The `%s` is replaced by a repository state string, by default just the branch name. See [the source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) for options and their meanings.